# error resizing image using react-native-image-resizer library on react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to reduce the image size on react native because of 413 HTTP code error.
I am using the react-native-image-resizer library for it. I am getting an
[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ImageResizerAndroid.createResizedImage')] error.

my photo.uri looks like this  "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fgre-be697e6c-57a9-4676-b1c2-9f6721a2a075/Camera/9e88e05c-96be-4212-b535-7b0544f2a967.jpg"

```
  ImageResizer.createResizedImage(photo.uri, height, width, "JPEG", 60, 0).then(
  (response) => {
     console.log(response);
  });
```